# Event Receiver Does Not Cancel In Explorer View

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, explorer-view

I have a document library with a `ItemAdding` event receiver registered to it that looks for whether a folder has been added and if so, cancels the folder creation.

This works fine in the GUI. However, when in Explorer view, although the event receiver fires, the event is not cancelled.

I have ran the debugger in Visual Studio and the below two lines are definitely being executed, so I can't understand why the event is not being cancelled?

```
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError; 
properties.ErrorMessage = "You cannot create folders here.";
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set

`properties.Cancel = true;`

Comment: I'll give this a try. But do you know why my code would work when in the browser and not when in Explorer?

Comment: It seems the `Cancel` property is obsolete. The `Status` property should be used instead, so my code is up to date. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventpropertiesbase.cancel.aspx

Comment: The issue is that when you add item to document library, the event receiver is triggered multiple times, now it depends where have you placed your CancelWithError statement

Comment: I have run the debugger and the event receiver only fires once, as it should.